# MySQL slow on subquery

Tags: mysql, optimization

This following query take 1-2 seconds for querying.

```
SELECT updated, COUNT( * ) count
FROM v2_subscription
WHERE ss_id IN (SELECT MAX(ss_id) ss_id FROM v2_subscription GROUP BY uid, card_id)
```

while the subquery do take only few milliseconds.

```
SELECT MAX(ss_id) ss_id FROM v2_subscription GROUP BY uid, card_id
```

I do have index on `uid`, `card_id` and both `uid, card_id`

It's my sql and i have no idea how to optimize this.

Please advise,

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: can an ss_id show up in more than one uid / card_id combo?

Comment: Why have the GROUP BY in the subquery?  It seems to serve no purpose.

Comment: Why have COUNT(*) when you are expecting exactly one row?

Comment: I'm sorry that the query i gave you might not quite make sense since it is a part of problem in the big query.

@pala_ No it cannot, that's why i need to have group by in subquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, May be it would help, let me know, if it does.

```
SELECT a.updated, COUNT( * ) count
FROM v2_subscription a 
inner join v2_subscription b 
on a.ss_id = max(b.ss_id)
GROUP BY b.uid, b.card_id
```

Or perhaps this

```
SELECT a.updated, COUNT( * ) count
    FROM v2_subscription a 
    inner join v2_subscription b 
    on a.ss_id = (SELECT MAX(b.ss_id) b.ss_id FROM v2_subscription b GROUP BY b.uid, b.card_id)
```

Comment: Another method i have found is to add "ORDER BY ss_id" in the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i have found the solution beside @arkumar above answer.
Adding "ORDER BY ss_id" inside the subquery also do the trick
Since without order by, the result of subquery do not have index.